# pymorphy2 определение опечаток

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymorphy2

Почему данное слово определяется как имя прилагательное (краткое)?
И можно ли с помощью этой библиотеки определить правильность данного слова?

```py
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
p = morph.parse('ашибка')[0]

print(p.tag)
```

Что выводит скрипт : ADJS,Qual femn,sing 
(КР_ПРИЛ,кач жр,ед)

Comment: https://github.com/bakwc/JamSpell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И можно ли с помощью этой библиотеки определить правильность данного слова?

Нет, нельзя, библиотека для этого не предназначена.

> Почему данное слово определяется как имя прилагательное (краткое)?

Смотрим все решения:

```
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
p = morph.parse('ашибка')

for item in p:
    print(item)
```

Вывод:

```
Parse(word='ашибка', tag=OpencorporaTag('ADJS,Qual femn,sing'), normal_form='ашибкий', score=0.6666666666666666, methods_stack=((DictionaryAnalyzer(), 'шибка', 11, 28), (UnknownPrefixAnalyzer(score_multiplier=0.5), 'а')))
Parse(word='ашибка', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,nomn'), normal_form='ашибка', score=0.3333333333333333, methods_stack=((FakeDictionary(), 'ашибка', 8, 0), (KnownSuffixAnalyzer(min_word_length=4, score_multiplier=0.5), 'шибка')))
```

Видим, что в первом случае действительно определилось как краткое прилагательное.

Стек методов разбора:

```
methods_stack=((DictionaryAnalyzer(), 'шибка', 11, 28), (UnknownPrefixAnalyzer(score_multiplier=0.5), 'а'))
```

Показывает, что "а" в начале было отброшено как неизвестная приставка, а слово "шибка" уже нашлось в словаре, и действительно: ["шибок"](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=379476) - или если как полное прилагательное - то "шибкий".

Второе решение - существительное женского рода, определилось по `FakeDictionary` ("ненастоящий" словарь), по сути если слова нет в словаре - то библиотека пытается "угадать" на какую часть речи это похоже.

Answer (score 1):

В какой-то степени определить правильность слова можно. Используем .word_is_known()

```
import pymorphy2
slovo='ашибка'
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer().word_is_known(slovo)
print(morph)  ## выведет False
slovo='ошибка'
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer().word_is_known(slovo)
print(morph)  ## выведет True
```